# Delete multiple comments

Tags: support, comments

Is there a way to delete multiple comments from report under `all actions -> comments` tab?
[image]

Comment: Not currently, no.

Answer (score 6):

You can go to each one and click the delete button.  There's no *other* way to delete multiple comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you're feeling adventurous, you can [leverage the Stack Overflow API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/delete-comment) to pull back a list of your comments, and then delete them instead.  You can batch it however you like then, depending on API limitations.  Outside of that, there's no concise way to do what you're looking for.